# TensorFlow NN embedded in C++ project

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have a C++ OpenCV-based project. I would like to incorporate CNN for object detection in this project. Should I consider TensorFlow as a good opportunity?

I know that almost everyone uses TensorFlow with Python. Is there any way to incorporate calculations done with TensorFlow into a C++ project? Should I consider something else (e.g. Caffe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. You should see the following link. I have recently worked on a project where I embedded TF model in c not cpp. But the idea is the same. See the following link

https://docs.python.org/3/extending/